# What counts as outliving another player in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I used to have a quest named "Outlive X players" (for this example let's use 300). Normally, outlive would mean surviving to another player in any way (like killing them or running away). However, sometimes I get 100 outlives in one battle, but of course haven't met or shot that many players.

Can I have more explanation on what an outlive is and what would count as an outlive in Fortnite BR?

Comment: Note that the maximum amount of 'outlives' you can get in one battle is 99 and not 100, as there are only 100 players per match (including yourself), and you cannot outlive yourself.

Comment: Every time another team player dies you gain 1 point.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It means to live longer in a match than other players.  Your kills don't matter.  The players you see don't matter.

If you are in 100 player match and you are the 90th player to die (putting you in 11th place), then you outlived 89 other players.

Comment: Or, equivalently: to "outlive" another player is to be alive when they die.